# Formatting a date in Codeigniter using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to change the format of a date that is being selected from a MySQL database but it is returning an error. I've looked online but I can't work our what I'm doing wrong.

The code that I am using in my model is as follows:

```
Public function get_news()
    {
        $this->db->select('id, text');
        $this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(date,'%W %D %M %Y')", FALSE);
        $this->db->limit(10);
        $this->db->order_by('date', 'desc');
        $query = $this->db->get('news');

        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
    }
```

The error is:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: date

Filename: views/news.php

Line Number: 22

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\tsh\CI\application\views\news.php
Line: 22
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\tsh\CI\application\controllers\home.php
Line: 99
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\tsh\public_html\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

View:

```
<?php foreach($news as $news_item) { ?>
<article class="article_text">
    <p class="segment_headding"><?php echo $news_item['date']; ?></p>
    <?php echo $news_item['text']; ?>
</article>
<?php } ?>
```

I'm sure it is just something silly that I've done wrong but I just can't see it.

Comment: You have an array that tries to use the 'date' index, which isn't defined. where is views/news.php and show the line in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view echos `$news_item['date']`, but in your query you have:

```
$this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(date,'%W %D %M %Y')", FALSE);
```

I am not too familiar with codeigniter, but I think this is probably not producing something that can be retrieved by `$news_item['date']`. You could try aliasing the formatted date

```
$this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(date,'%W %D %M %Y') AS fdate", FALSE);
```

and then using that in your view: `$news_item['fdate']`.